# How to update Account Sequence

Tags: javascript-sdk, sequence-number

I have to handle a concurrent activation of 2 accounts.
I am using a lock mechanism so that I can handle manually the sequence number.
I am using bumpSequence operation to try and update the sequence of the account, but it does not update the sequence.

```
  const txBuilder = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(fromAccount, { fee: "100", networkPassphrase: Stellar.NetworkPassphrase })
  txBuilder.operations = [StellarSdk.Operation.bumpSequence({bumpTo: newSequence}),
      StellarSdk.Operation.createAccount({
        destination: publicKey,
        startingBalance: String(startingBalance),
      })];
  const tx = txBuilder.setTimeout(30).build();
  tx.sign(Stellar.MasterKeys);
  console.log("transaction sequence: " + tx.sequence);       <------ here it still prints the old sequence
```

No exceptions are thrown, except the error when submitting the second transaction (tx_bad_seq) because it was created while the previous one was being submitted, hence using the old sequence.